# IP addresses of DNS Queries Show Up Backwards in Wireshark

Tags: vpn, dns, wireshark, dnscrypt-proxy

I have been using DNSCrypt with dnsmasq on my Ubuntu 14.10 machine. When running a dumcap via Wireshark, I've noticed a couple of odd occurrences lately. Firstly, after disconnecting from my VPN, with the hypothetical IP address of 10.8.0.13, I see this:

```
.............13.0.8.10.in-addr.arpa..................13.0.8.10.in-addr.arpa.....
```

And let's say my VPN server IP is 123.456.78.91, than the queries look like this:

```
9143    584.912799000   localhost   localhost   DNS 88  Standard query 0xc198  PTR 19.78.654.321.in-addr.arpa
```

And of course, the answer to these queries are always this:

```
9144    584.912945000   localhost   localhost   DNS 88  Standard query response 0xc198 No such name
```

It even happens for broadcast addresses:

```
125 37.371037000    localhost   localhost   DNS 90  Standard query 0x8e53  PTR 250.255.255.239.in-addr.arpa
```

Everytime this happens, the queries are followed by a bunch of 'conntecion resets' and other warnings. Is this normal? Is dnsmasq interfering with DNSCrypt-proxy? I tried running dnscrypt without a dns cache, but than I noticed that queries to my localhost and sometimes local network were being forwarded to the nameservers. And if that's not bad enough, I've had to reset my router twice in last week (OpenWRT) because sometimes DNS would break altogether, and Wireshark would show that my local domain, ".lann" was being added to every single query the system made, for example:

```
askubuntu.com.lann
```

How should I fix this? It seems my DNS is totally broken. I'm totally confused.

Answer (score 0):

while using tcpdump, use -n This will tell tcpdump to NOT to resolve any IP's or domain names. What you are seeing is the reverse lookup for the IP's.

Excerpt from tcpdump man page
-n     Don't convert host addresses to names.  This can be used to avoid DNS lookups.